# Seeing partitions on hard drive in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning

How do you see and adjust partitions on a hard drive in Ubuntu 14.04? I want to add Openelec to my second partition.

Comment: What's Openelec?

Answer (score 1):

try to used Gparted, it is easy and straightforward